# Parse a Directory of json files with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have been looking for how to do this but I cannot. 
I have a directory of .json files and I am supposed to parse each one.
I know I have to use glob and os.
I feel like the logic behind it is loop over the directory and when reading each file extract the data that is needed, but I cannot find anywhere to help me nor do I know the syntax. 
If its against stack rules and people think this is me asking for answers to homework that is fine I can just search elsewhere, this isn't homework I just don't understand.

Comment: Have you looked at the `json` module? That's kind of the crux of the whole thing. I doubt you need the `os` module if you're using `glob`; you need one or the other, but not both. Add the `open` function, and I think that's it.

Comment: Rather than trying to do everything at once, start one step at a time? Start from using [`open`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) on just _one_ file and pass it into [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load).  Now you have a function that does that, and you can keep going to a static list, then a generated list produced by glob.

Comment: `json` lib is your best friend here you could orchestra with `os` and `sys`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your JSON files are named with a `.json` extension and that they are in the same directory that you are running the script from:

```
import json
from glob import glob

data = []
for file_name in glob('*.json'):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        data.append(json.load(f))
```

This will give you a list of parsed JSON objects (dictionaries and/or lists).

If you need to access the files in another directory you can construct your glob pattern like this:

```
import os.path

pattern = os.path.join('/path/to/json/files', '*.json')
for file_name in glob(pattern):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was struggling with very similar issue. I end up writing my own script for that:
https://github.com/tmdag/makedirtree

It was easier to create directories using Unix 'tree' command and re-create them with

```
pathlib.Path(s_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```